# How to read and run files on hard drive from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, networking

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:
  A user will have to match his fingerprint (captured image) with an image stored in the server. I've implemented the image matching program in OpenCV and it's a .exe on disk. The output of this is flag.txt.
 Basically if the value of flag.txt is non-zero the user may gain access to the next webpage.

The question is - how to I run the .exe and read the contents of the resultant text file (saved on the hard-drive) from a webpage?

EDIT - please note, I am not sure under which tags this falls.

Comment: @Tuzo not 'anyone' creating the flag.txt. If the picture they upload matches with the original image then the program creates the text file and writes the flag value as non-zero if its an exact match.

Comment: What language is your webpage written in?  Are you going to perform the authorization on the server?  You've tagged your question javascript so it makes it sound like you are going to do the authorization in the browser. If so, then that is not secure since the user can manipulate javascript to bypass your security.

Comment: would you please point me to resources/links that gives an idea how to do this? - I chose javascript because i assumed that i would be using this when trying to integrate the .exe into a webpage. I've mostly done image-processing in C lately, not much idea about web services honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement kind of web service which will execute you .exe files and do other logic and access this web service from web page. Browser won't allow web page do such actions because of security reasons

Comment: would you please point me to resources/links that gives an idea how to do this? I've mostly done image-processing in C lately, not much idea about web services honestly.

Comment: @AruniRC it make sense to read on WCF services topic, a couple of links http://www.packtpub.com/article/implementing-basic-wcf-windows-communication-foundation-service - hello world with WCF, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729746.aspx - top level page for this topic in msdn